# mysql orderby on column after groupby

Tags: mysql, group-by, sql-order-by

I have a table with the following  fields: season, collection, product_key, aggregated_sale. following query is not giving expected output

```
select
    t.* 
from
    (SELECT * FROM rank_processing.aggregate_season_product 
       order by aggregated_sale) t
group by
    t.collection,
    t.forecast_name,
    t.product_key;
```

sample input

```
ss, f1, 1, 11
ss, f1, 3, 10
ss, f1, 2, 5
ss, f2, 5, 11
ss, f2, 4, 7
```

expected output is

```
ss, f1, 2, 5
ss, f1, 3, 10
ss, f1, 1, 11
ss, f2, 4, 7
ss, f2, 5, 11
```

Comment: sample input
ss, f1, 1, 11
ss, f1, 3, 10
ss, f1, 2, 5
ss, f2, 5, 11
ss, f2, 4, 7
expected output is
ss, f1, 2, 5
ss, f1, 3, 10
ss, f1, 1, 11
ss, f2, 4, 7
ss, f2, 5, 11

Comment: I'm so confused. How is that sorted?

Comment: `GROUP BY` mysql's implementation performs sorting for its internal puposes, so your `ORDER BY` in the nested query doesn't change anything

Comment: @Joe Frambach: seems like it's sorted by `col1, col2, col4`

Comment: i want expected output for above input.:)

Answer (score 1):

Note that without explicit `ORDER BY` clause server is NOT required to sort your results, even if `GROUP BY` is present.

If you want to order your results, simply add appropriate `ORDER BY`, something like that:

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM (SELECT * FROM rank_processing.aggregate_season_product 
    ORDER BY aggregated_sale) t
GROUP BY
    t.collection,
    t.forecast_name,
    t.product_key
ORDER BY
    t.collection,
    t.forecast_name,
    t.product_key
```

Another question here is that `ORDER BY` inside subquery is useless, and you should even expand that subquery to eliminate it completely.

Comment: Sorting in a nested query makes no sense.

Comment: @zerkms: which is why I mentioned that it should be eliminated

Comment: Why not show the result query then? PS: `GROUP BY` internally performs sorting, so `ORDER BY` over the same columns is redundant. PPS: OP wanted the result set sorted over `collection, forecast_name, aggregated_sale`, not `collection, forecast_name, product_key`

Comment: @zerkms: `GROUP BY` *can* do internal sorting, it does NOT have to. This is the whole point of this answer - if you want to guarantee order, you MUST add `ORDER BY`

Comment: for mysql it **always does**, by definition. You can even specify `GROUP BY col DESC` if you wish

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to use a sub-query? This query should give you the result.

```
SELECT * FROM rank_processing.aggregate_season_product 
group by
  collection,
  forecast_name,
  product_key
order by season, collection, aggregated_sale
```

I'm guessing, you wouldn't even need a `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT * FROM rank_processing.aggregate_season_product 
order by season, collection, aggregated_sale
```

Comment: Using columns that aren't used in `GROUP BY` or aggregate function would lead to unpredictable results.

Comment: @user2450833: the proposed solution is ideologically incorrect

Comment: @zerkms I don't understand; please explain. The question says there are 4 columns and 3 are grouped by with a * in the select. That would lead to indeterminate result. Since there is no aggregate there, it makes sense to get rid of group by.

Comment: That there is no aggregate makes it very easy to downvote and ignore the question, since OP hasn't put any thought into what exactly is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8c423/9)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE aggregate_season_product
    (`season` varchar(2), `collection` varchar(2), `forecast_name` varchar(2), `product_key` int, `aggregated_sale` int)
;

INSERT INTO aggregate_season_product
    (`season`, `collection`, `forecast_name`, `product_key`, `aggregated_sale`)
VALUES
    ('ss', 'cc', 'f1', 1, 11),
    ('ss', 'cc', 'f1', 3, 10),
    ('ss', 'cc', 'f1', 2, 5),
    ('ss', 'cc', 'f2', 5, 11),
    ('ss', 'cc', 'f2', 4, 7)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
select * 
from aggregate_season_product 
where season = 'ss' and collection = 'cc'
ORDER by
    season,
    collection,
    forecast_name,
    aggregated_sale
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8c423/9/0)**:

```
| SEASON | COLLECTION | FORECAST_NAME | PRODUCT_KEY | AGGREGATED_SALE |
|--------|------------|---------------|-------------|-----------------|
|     ss |         cc |            f1 |           2 |               5 |
|     ss |         cc |            f1 |           3 |              10 |
|     ss |         cc |            f1 |           1 |              11 |
|     ss |         cc |            f2 |           4 |               7 |
|     ss |         cc |            f2 |           5 |              11 |
```